# inner <ul> in nav full width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the following example in a horizontal html5/css3 menu bar. The menu is in the header and spreads always 100%:

```
<nav id="navi">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><em class="visuallyhidden">Lorem ipsum: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</em></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><em class="visuallyhidden">Lorem ipsum: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</em></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                       
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                       
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Natur</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nahrung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gastgewerbe</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Textilien</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Schönheit, Sport</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gestaltung, Kunst</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Druck</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bau</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gebäudetechnik</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Holz, Innenausbau</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fahrzeuge</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Elektrotechnik</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Metall, Maschinen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Chemie, Physik</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Planung, Konstruktion</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Verkauf</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wirtschaft, Verwaltung</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Verkehr, Logistik</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Informatik</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kultur</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gesundheit</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bildung, Soziales</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <ul>
            </nav>
```

If I hover / click the "menu 1", "hidden submenu" comes up nicely **underneath** the "menu 1", but not on a full width as the menu bar itself. How can I accomplish that the submenu will show up as 100% (full site)?

My css as requested:

```
.header nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #425863;
}
.header nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #425863;
} 
.header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 34px 14px 34px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.154em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3 ease-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.3 ease-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}
.header nav ul li:target > ul {
  max-height: 200px;
}
.header nav ul li ul {
  display: inline;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
}
.header nav ul li ul li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.header nav ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 44px;
  color: #000000;
}
.header nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e2007a !important;
}
.header nav ul li ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.header nav ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #e2007a;
}
.header nav ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
.header nav ul li:target > ul {
  max-height: none;
}
```

Sadly, I do not know how to create such a fiddle :(

**Example**

[A live example](https://www.brack.ch/) or my image
[image]

---

**EDIT:** I have tried this now: `position: absolute` on the `ul` elements which contain the second level. Then I set `width: 986px` as a test. What I got was 
[image]

This is only working for the first menu element (and this is what I want for all elements). The other submenus open underneath the first level and then vanish in the right of the screen. So still, no solution.

I have also created one of them jsfiddles: [Here to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44bzdu7j/)

Comment: can you post your css or create a fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

You miss a close `li`. So in your problem. If i understand right you want to display sub menu to 100% width. One solution is to set `width: 100%` to `.header nav ul li ul`:

```css
.header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #425863;
}
.header nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #425863;
}
.header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 34px 14px 34px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.154em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3 ease-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.3 ease-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}
.header nav ul li:target > ul {
  max-height: 200px;
}
.header nav ul li ul {
  display: inline;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  width: 100%;/*add width 100%*/
}
.header nav ul li ul li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.header nav ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 44px;
  color: #000000;
}
.header nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e2007a !important;
}
.header nav ul li ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.header nav ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #e2007a;
}
.header nav ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
.header nav ul li:target > ul {
  max-height: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">hidden submenu</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, if I add the `width: 100%` something weird happens, I [show you here](http://i61.tinypic.com/azevjt.png).The `<ul>` seems to be doing the `width: 100%` from the upper menu onwards, although I would like it to spread all over the site horizontally :/

Comment: hmm give me some time please.

Comment: No problem. I have added the definitive menu html code - maybe something is wrong in there; I haven't found it so far.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution myself. The trick lied within the positioning of the outer containers, as well as left: 0px; and right: 0px;

For others struggeling with this I have updated the jsfiddle, and I will post the new css in here (HTML stays the same), in case the fiddle gets deleted.

CSS:

```
.header nav {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 height: 45px;
}
.header nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #425863;
}
.header nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #425863;
  /* First level */
}
.header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 25px 14px 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.154em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3 ease-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.3 ease-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
} 
.header nav ul li:target > ul {
  max-height: 200px;
} 
.header nav ul li ul {
  display: inline;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
}
.header nav ul li ul li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*Second level - first entries*/
}
.header nav ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.0em;
} 
.header nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e2007a !important;
} 
.header nav ul li ul li ul {
  display: inline;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
} 
.header nav ul li ul li ul li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Third level - normal entries */
}
.header nav ul li ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.0em;
} 
.header nav ul li ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e2007a !important;
} 
.header nav ul li ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.header nav ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #e2007a;
} 
.header nav ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
} 
.header nav ul li:target > ul {
  max-height: none;
}
```